# Finding the corresponding column number to the maximum value

Tags: python

I want to find the column number that corresponds to the highest value in a row.

I need to write it as a function that takes the following dictionary as a argument:

```
    {'1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
    '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
    '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
    '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
    '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
    '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}}
```

my first row is number 4. I find the highest number by:

```
max(d['4'].values())
```

From the matrix representation of the dictionary i know that this number is in column number 2. And I want my function to return this number. How?

Comment: Why are you indexing the dictionary with string representations of integers instead of `int`s?

Comment: This is how the dictionary is given to me in the exercise

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
max(d['4'].iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Comment: When i use that i line I get en error saying invalid syntax and suggesting '='

Comment: Please paste the exact error message, and (if you can) pastebin your code too.

Comment: If I wan't the function to return the column number of the largest value in the dictionary, so without knowing the row. Is that possible?

Comment: @anne: Yes, it is. Reduce each row to its largest value, then reduce the entire dictionary the same way.  `r = max(map(lambda i: (i[0], max(i[1].iteritems(), key=lambda j: j[1])), d.iteritems()), key=lambda x: x[1][1])`  It's ugly, but it works.  `r[0]` is the outer dict key, `r[1][0]` is the inner dict key, and `r[1][1]` is the value that was determined to be the largest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `items` method of a dictionary:

```
col,value = max(d['4'].items(), key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Breaking it down to see how this works:

- `d['4'].items()` returns a list (or iterable object in python3) of key-value tuples
- `max` takes a second argument which is a function that is used to actually compare the items.  In this case, we take the second item in each tuple (the value)
- `max` returns the entire tuple, and we disassemble it using `col,value = max(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: max(d['4'].items(), key=lambda (k,v):v)[0]
Out[11]: '2'
```

where `d` is your dictionary.

Comment: If a write  print max(d['4'].items(), key=lambda (k,v):v)[0]
I get a syntax error, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def key_of_max_value(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        yield k, max((v, k) for k, v in v.iteritems())
```

Test code:

```
def test_key_of_max_value():
    d = {
        '1': {'3': 0, '2': 1, '5': 1, '4': 0, '6': 29},
        '3': {'1': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1, '6': 1},
        '2': {'1': 13, '3': 1, '5': 21, '4': 0, '6': 0},
        '5': {'1': 39, '3': 0, '2': 1, '4': 0, '6': 14},
        '4': {'1': 1, '3': 1, '2': 17, '5': 2, '6': 0},
        '6': {'1': 0, '3': 43, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 1}
    }
    for k, (value, column_key) in key_of_max_value(d):
        print k, column_key, value    

test_key_of_max_value()
```

Results:

```
1 6 29
3 6 1
2 5 21
5 1 39
4 2 17
6 3 43
```